# Show a view after Response from Server in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am facing some issue in displaying a view in my view controller. I have made a custom view in a view controller which is shown when the response is 0 or getting correct response. Made two custom views . When the response comes 0 it shows view1 in which user click register button and user go to register page and when the response get value than it should display view2 in which it gets pin. Now i'm trying to display the view but i'm not getting it. The code i tried is this,

```
NSString *string1 = _Mobile.text;

NSLog(@"ID is %@",string1);

NSString *string2=@"&action=pin";


NSString *urll=@"MyURL";
NSString *string3 = [urll stringByAppendingString:string1];
NSString *final=[string3 stringByAppendingString:string2];

NSLog(@"URL %@",final);

_indicator.hidden=NO;
[_indicator startAnimating];
NSString *targetUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",final];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:targetUrl]];

[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:
  ^(NSData * _Nullable data,
    NSURLResponse * _Nullable response,
    NSError * _Nullable error) {
      [_indicator stopAnimating];
      _indicator.hidden=YES;
      NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      NSLog(@"Data received: %@", myString);

      if([myString intValue] == 0){
          [self RegAlert];
      }else if ([myString intValue]==response){
          [self PinAlert];
      }

  }] resume];
```

The function i'm writing is this,

```
-(void)RegAlert{
    _regView.hidden=NO;
    [self.regView bounceIntoView:self.view direction:DCAnimationDirectionLeft
}

-(void)PinAlert{
    _pinView.hidden=NO;
        [self.pinView bounceIntoView:self.view direction:DCAnimationDirectionLeft];
}
```

My response coming from service is this when its 0 this

> {"data":"0"}

When its right then it shows this pin

> {"data":[{"pin":"5583"}]}

Comment: Is calling directly to [self RegAlert] or [self PinAlert] able to show your view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code for json before dispatch_async block

```
 NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                      options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers 
                                        error:nil];
  NSString *value = json[@"data"];
```

Modify your ui update like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            if([value isEqualToString: @"0"]){
                [self RegAlert];
            }else {
                [self PinAlert];
            }            
        });
```

Note: UI update should be run on the main queue, hope it helps you

```
-(void)RegAlert{
    pinView.hidden=YES;
    _regView.hidden=NO;
    [self.regView bounceIntoView:self.view direction:DCAnimationDirectionLeft];
}

-(void)PinAlert{
    _regView.hidden=YES;
    _pinView.hidden=NO;
        [self.pinView bounceIntoView:self.view direction:DCAnimationDirectionLeft];
}
```

Comment: It is showing only view1 in both cases whether the response is 0 or we get a pin from response, how can i get the view2 , i think else condition is not working. @user1000

Comment: @Oneeb if you make it just else then what is the result, see my updated answer

Comment: no not yet its showing same view1 again. Sorry for late reply. @user1000

Comment: @Oneeb you are showing self.view for both pinAlert and regAlert? is this right?

Comment: [self RegAlert]; it shows view1 and [self PinAlert ]; it shows view2, but according to ur code it is showing only view1 in both cases. @user1000

Comment: @Oneeb please put a debug in else part and see if it reaches there, and see my updated answer, modify your functions like this

Comment: It is not going inside the else condition. @user1000

Comment: @Oneeb it means that myString is always 0, does it show different data or 0 always?

Comment: @Oneeb check what does this statement display in console: NSLog(@"Data received: %@", myString);

Comment: When we put mobile number correct than it shows a pin of that number like this in console {"data":[{"pin":"5583"}]}. @user1000

Comment: when the mobile no is registered first it shows a pin behind that number like this {"data":[{"pin":"5583"}]} in Mystring

Comment: @Oneeb I have updated the if condition, see if it helps, please ask if you face problem

Comment: it showing error here  if([myString isEqualToString: @"{"data":"0"}"]) in @"{"data":"0"}"] it is not written in correct way

Comment: @Oneeb check my updated answer, error was due to double quotes, you need to escape them inside a string using \

Comment: It is not entering in if condition now. @user1000

Comment: @Oneeb I have updated my answer, please check the code and add the new twol lines before async block and tell me the result, please modify the if condition also

Comment: What are these two in this line  NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData
                                      options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers 
                                        error:&jsonError]; . Its giving error in ObjecctData and jsonError. What are these two for? . @user1000

Comment: @Oneeb replace ObjectData with data and put nil instead of jsonError and check again

Comment: @Oneeb these two statements convert the json data that you are receiving and convert them to dictionary, see if it helps

Comment: Thank God after a long struggle it is working perfect now. Thanks for ur time and support.:) @user1000

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide both view before doing any process on it. So when you try to show, it should display only one view.

Here is some minor updation in code:

```
[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:
  ^(NSData * _Nullable data,
    NSURLResponse * _Nullable response,
    NSError * _Nullable error) {
      [_indicator stopAnimating];
      _indicator.hidden=YES;
      NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      NSLog(@"Data received: %@", myString);

    // Here we need to hide both view initial
    _regView.hidden=NO;
    _pinView.hidden=NO;

      if([myString intValue] == 0){
          [self RegAlert];
      }else if ([myString intValue]==response){
          [self PinAlert];
      }

  }] resume];
```

You need to add below two line before doing any animation or process on view.

```
// Here we need to hide both view initial
_regView.hidden=NO;
_pinView.hidden=NO;
```

Comment: They r hidden as default i have hide them from storyboard but now it is showing view1 only